# Is there a good simulation of multiple finite square quantum wells in which energy levels are accurately determined?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics

There was an excellent site at Kansas State University but it no longer works in most browsers.  I'm looking for a replacement.  The solution of energy levels for 2 to 10 individual finite quantum wells shows the origin of band theory of solids.  The 10 wells are a "model" solid.  This is much, much better than the Kronig Penney model because it shows how the discrete energy levels of an atom (a single square well) become a "band" of closely spaced energy levels as we add atoms.  Kronig Penney relies on a belief in the Bloch Theorem and generally goes beyond what can be expected in an introductory Semiconductor Physics class.

Comment: Does it have to be a website and interactive?

Comment: An interactive website would be best but I have some resources that could turn something more raw into such a site.